# Python Paramiko exec_command doesn't print few commands outputs

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to build a Python script using Paramiko which should SSH Linux server and execute a command, some commands output is working for example `df -f,netstat` but some of them aren't for example `onstat -,ifconfig`. Need help solving this issue.

```
#!/usr/pkg/bin/python

#Importing modules
import paramiko
import time

#setting parameters like host IP, username, passwd and number of iterations to gather cmds
HOST = 'x.x.x.x'
USER = 'abc'
PASS = 'efg'
ITERATION = 3

client1=paramiko.SSHClient()
#Add missing client key
client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
#connect to CUCM
client1.connect(HOST,username=USER,password=PASS)
print("SSH connection to %s established" %HOST)
#Gather commands and read the output from stdout
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command("onstat -")
time.sleep(2)
for line in stdout.readlines():
       print(line)
client1.close()
print("Logged out of device %s" %HOST)
```

Any thought how to resolve this?

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: No error. I see not output after ssh login
=========== RESTART===========
SSH connection to x.x.x.x established
Logged out of device x.x.x.x>>>